# It will not give space - into the code section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how if I fill out name and last name in this form but lacks both email and password, you will see it and write like this:

"**Du mangler adgangskodeprofilbillede**"

What I would like that the strap was to make it like this:

"**Du mangler adgangskode, profilbillede**"

It could also be that it was both the first and last name as the missing but still have to do the same.

but if I have not written anything in content at all so it may well come back and write it nicely ie

"**Du mangler Email, Password, Fornavn, Efternavn, Profilbillede**"

I've written some of it in Danish so we may also see only error

```
$(function () {
    var $opretbruger = $('form[name="opretbruger"]'),
    $usr = $("#email"),
    $pwd = $("#pass1"),
    $navn = $("#fornavn"),
    $efter = $("#efternavn"),
    $pb = $("#pb");

    $opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {
        var msg = "Du mangler ",
        usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
        pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== ""),
        navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== ""),
        efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== ""),
        pb = ($efter.val().trim() !== "");

        msg += !usr ? "E-mail" : "";
    msg += !usr && !pwd ? ", " : "";
        msg += !pwd ? "kodeord" : "";
    msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn ? ", " : "";
        msg += !navn ? "Fornavn" : "";
    msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter ? ", " : "";
        msg += !efter ? "Efternavn" : "";
    msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter && !pb ? ", " : "";
        msg += !pb ? "Profilbillede" : "";

        var valid = pwd && usr && navn && efter;
        if (!valid) {
            alert(msg);
        }

        return valid;
    });
});
```

EIDT

```
    $(function () {
    var $opretbruger = $('form[name="opretbruger"]'),
        $usr = $("#email"),
        $pwd = $("#pass1"),
        $navn = $("#fornavn"),
        $efter = $("#efternavn"),
        $pb = $("#pb");

    $opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {

        var errors = [],
        valid = true,
        usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
        pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== ""),
        navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== ""),
        efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== ""),
        pb = ($efter.val().trim() !== "");

        if (!usr) errors.push("E-mail");
        if (!pwd) errors.push ("kodeord");
        if (!navn) errors.push("Fornavn");
        if (!efter) errors.push ("Efternavn");
        if (!pb) errors.push("Profilbillede");

        if (errors.length) {
            var last = errors.length>1 ? ((errors.length>2) ? "," : "") + " & " + errors.pop() : "";
            var "Du mangler " + msg = errors.join(", ") + last;
            valid = false;
            alert(msg);
        }

        return valid;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is with all of the string add, just use an array with join

```
$opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {

    var errors = [],
    valid = true,
    usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
    pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== ""),
    navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== ""),
    efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== ""),
    pb = ($efter.val().trim() !== "");

    if (!usr) errors.push("E-mail");
    if (!pwd) errors.push ("kodeord");
    /* rest of checks here */

    if (errors.length) {
        var msg = "Du mangler " + errors.join(", ");
        valid = false;
        alert(msg);
    }

    return valid;

});
```

---

If you want to make the output a little more fancy adding a "&" for the last item, something like this would work

```
if (errors.length) {
    var last = errors.length>1 ? ((errors.length>2) ? "," : "") + " & " + errors.pop() : "";
    var msg = "Du mangler " + errors.join(", ") + last;
    valid = false;
    alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can not exactly see how I was going to build it in :)

Comment: You do not know how to add this into your code? Remove the `msg += ...` code with this.

Comment: Well valid is not defined now...  Updated code to add valid

Comment: I can not exactly see how to set the code together that it will work as you write, I can see it smartly into the rock.

Comment: Made the changes... Can you fill in the rest?

Comment: AHHH, typo...lol,  `var "Du mangler " + msg = errors.join(", ") + last;` is wrong... Pasted code in wrong spot

Comment: What you mean on its?

Comment: Wiiii now its work for me and thanks for help, and i have like u code! :)